# Jsoup won't extract src attr

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

```
 // Title AsyncTask
private class getArticles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements els = document.select("div.category3-image > a > img");
            System.out.print(els);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Doing this works, displays the following items:

```
I/System.out﹕ <img width="650" height="400" src="http://www.somesite.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/11937978_482236235278145_7661294603539537192_o-650x400.jpg" class="attachment-small-thumb wp-post-image" alt="11937978_482236235278145_7661294603539537192_o-650x400">
09-02 20:43:31.191    2969-3005/net.android I/System.out﹕ <img width="650" height="400" src="http://www.somesite.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Screenshot_16-650x400.jpg" class="attachment-small-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Screenshot_16-650x400">
```

I tried wrapping it in `for(Element e : els)`, retrieving inside and outside of for function, passed it to a string and used `System.out.print(stringname)`

used both,

```
 String absoluteUrl = els.absUrl("src");  //absolute URL on src

 String srcValue = els.attr("src");
```

But it just doesn't work. I tried searching on Stackoverflow, but no problems similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

`els` is of type Elements, i.e. a list of Element. Only Element has the `attr()` method. So try:

```
Elements els = document.select("div.category3-image > a > img");
Element el = els.first();
System.out.print(el.attr("src"));
```

Comment: Doesn't print anything.

Comment: It would really help if you provide an example of your observation. Without the HTML source is it kind of hard to spot the problem.